# i am not able to insatll my project pod getting this error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

[!] Unable to find a specification for `Crashlytics`  You have either:  * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.  * mistyped the name or version.  * n

Please check the below images

And i have searched the  error and get the issue on the github
[Click here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/152)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the command below in terminal:

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: thanx for the answer , i have used the above command and getting this error please check the link:- https://ibb.co/QFNSKWt

Comment: below `pod repo update` there should be a lot of logs, but that can't be seen in your snapshot.

Comment: There is no any log i m getting only this single line - Updating spec repo `trunk` below the command pod repo update

Comment: you should check your Podfile, try to remove specific version or host of this pod, delete Podfile.lock file, and `pod install` again

Comment: Now i have deleted my podfille.lock file and pod install again  and getting same error please check screenshots.    https://ibb.co/qpPZrs1
https://ibb.co/5Ys01jV
https://ibb.co/ZMmvD8G

Comment: did you try `pod install --repo-update`, it can force update your repo before install pods

Comment: No i haven't try this command..pod install --rep update....should i try this???